# Реализация Early exit в функции GO

Tags: golang, шаблоны-проектирования

```go
    for i, l1Length := 0, len(l1); i <= l1Length-l2Length; i++ {
        if l1[i] == l2[0] {
            for j := 1; j < l2Length; j++ {
                if i+j == l1Length || l1[i+j] != l2[j] {
                    break
                }
                return true
            }
        }
    }
```

Не совсем понимаю, как можно инвертировать первое условие if( на второй строчке ) и в нем сделать break, что-бы внутренний for стал на уровень выше.Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не `continue` ищете?

```golang
for i, l1Length := 0, len(l1); i <= l1Length-l2Length; i++ {
    if l1[i] != l2[0] {
        continue
    }

    for j := 1; j < l2Length; j++ {
        if i+j == l1Length || l1[i+j] != l2[j] {
            break
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А вы не можете подсказать мне статьи с более детальным разбором данного паттерна. Я не совсем понимаю, как он реализуется в go. Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: Не думаю, что такие статьи есть, ибо этот «шаблон проектирования» буквально описывается своим названием: «ранний выход». Если вы знаете го, то вам этого достаточно. Если нет — читайте [Спецификацию](https://golang.org/ref/spec). Можете также поискать близкое понятие «Pyramid Of Doom».